# How to assign an event listener to every link I create in a forEach loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I am using a forEach loop and creating a link based on a condition. However, the problem I am facing is that the event listener is only added to the last item. I know this question has been asked before and I know the reason for the issue is Hoisting and I should use closure. I have tried to do that but I do not think I am doing it correctly. I would really appreciate any help as I am kind of stuck. Below are some snippets from my code (I have deleted some pieces from the code for the purpose of the question):

```
    function edit(post, post_id){

    alert(post_id);

    }
function load_posts(event) {
    fetch(`/posts?start=${start}&end=${end}`)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        
        document.querySelector('#posts').innerHTML = "<div></div>";
        
        let c = 0;
        data.forEach(i => {
            if (c === data.length - 1){ 
                return; 
                };
            document.querySelector('#posts').innerHTML += `<div class = 'border' >`

            let current_user = document.getElementById("logged_in").innerHTML;

            document.querySelector('#posts').innerHTML += `<div class="row" ><div class="col-2" 
            id = border${i.id}></div>
            </div></div>`;
            if (i.user_id === parseInt(current_user)){
                let element = document.createElement('a');
                element.innerHTML = "Edit";
                element.setAttribute('data-id', `${i.id}`);
                element.setAttribute('data-post', `${i.id}`);
                element.setAttribute('href', `#${i.id}`);
                element.addEventListener('click', function() 
                {edit(this.dataset.id,this.dataset.post);});
                console.log(element);
                document.querySelector(`#border${i.id}`).append(element);
                };
        }
        c++;
    });});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning to the `innerHTML` of an element will corrupt any existing listeners its children have:

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('clicked');
});
container.innerHTML += '';
// click listener doesn't work anymore now
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button>click</button>
</div>
```

Create the element with `document.createElement` instead of concatenating an HTML string:

```
const currentUserId = Number(document.getElementById("logged_in").textContent);
data.slice(0, data.length - 1).forEach((i, index) => {
  const newPost = document.querySelector('#posts').appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
  newPost.className = 'border';
  newPost.innerHTML = `<div class="row" ><div class="col-2" 
            id = border${i.id}></div>
            </div>`;
  if (i.user_id === currentUserId) {
    let element = document.createElement('a');
    element.textContent = "Edit";
    element.dataset.id = i.id;
    element.dataset.post = i.id;
    element.href = `#${i.id}`;
    element.addEventListener('click', function() {
      edit(this.dataset.id, this.dataset.post);
    });
    document.querySelector(`#border${i.id}`).append(element);
  }
});
```

I'd also highly recommend changing your `i` variable name to something else - `i` is almost always used to indicate the *index* that you're iterating over. The *element* being iterated over should not be named `i` - call it something like `postData` instead, to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thank you so much!! this solved the problem, I just removed the below line data.slice(0, data.length - 1).forEach((i, index) => {. I was obviously looking in the wrong direction.